# How do you calculate lims that are 0/0 without L'Hospital's law?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

*I prefer hint more than a complete solution if possible.

edit: Let the second equation be x, can I do $1/x$ and solve with polynomial division?

Hi,

for those two lims, we get lim (0/0) and we are not allowed to use L'Hospital's law in order to solve.

1.$ \lim_{x\rightarrow10}\frac{x-10}{\sqrt{3x+6}-6}$

2.$\lim_{x\rightarrow(-2)}\frac{4x^3-15x+2}{x^4-3x-22}$

Do you have a hint for me?

Thanks

Comment: Hint for 1 ... rationalize the denominator.  Hint for 2 ... factor.

Comment: Guys if i divide 1 by the second equation can we do polynomial division there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factoring and conjugation are two methods that you can use to eliminate the removable discontinuities.

1. $\lim\limits_{x\to 10} \dfrac{x-10}{\sqrt{3x+6}-6}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{3x+6}+6}{\sqrt{3x+6}+6}$
2. $\lim\limits_{x\to -2}\dfrac{4x^3-15x+2}{x^4-3x-22}=\dfrac{(x+2)(\cdots)}{(x+2)(\cdots)}$

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I think it worked now.

Comment: if we call the first equation x, can we do 1/x and than do polynomial division?

Comment: $\dfrac{x^4-3x-22}{4x^3-15x+2}=\dfrac{1}{4}x+\dfrac{\frac{15}{4}x^2-\frac{7}{2}x-22}{4x^3-15x+2}$.  How will you be using this information?

Comment: No, we get like this:
$\dfrac{x^4-3x-22}{4x^3-15x+2}$
can we now do polynomial division?

Comment: My above comment had the division done.

Comment: Oh sorry, ok i understand now, it didnt solve the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

1) Rationalize the denominator.

2) Since the numerator and denominator are both $0$ when $x=-2$, you can conclude that $(x+2)$ is a factor of both by the Remainder Theorem.  Factor and cancel out that term.

Comment: Thank you also, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

For
$\lim_{x\rightarrow(-2)}\frac{4x^3-15x+2}{x^4-3x-22}
$,
let $x = y-2$.

This becomes

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{4(y-2)^3-15(y-2)+2}{(y-2)^4-3(y-2)-22}
&=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y (4 y^2 - 24 y + 33)}{y (y^3 - 8 y^2 + 24 y - 35)}\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{4 y^2 - 24 y + 33}{ y^3 - 8 y^2 + 24 y - 35}\\
&=-\frac{33}{ 35}\\
\end{array}
$

---

(added later)

And for
$\lim_{x\rightarrow10}\frac{x-10}{\sqrt{3x+6}-6}
$,
let $y = x-10$.
This becomes

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{\sqrt{3(y+10)+6}-6}
&=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{\sqrt{3y+36}-6}\\
&=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{6\sqrt{1+y/12}-6}\\
&=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{6(1+y/24+O(1/y^2))-6}\\
&=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{y/4+O(1/y)}\\
&=4\\
&\text{or}\\
&=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{\sqrt{3y+36}-6}\frac{\sqrt{3y+36}+6}{\sqrt{3y+36}+6}\\
&=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y(\sqrt{3y+36}+6)}{(3y+36)-36}\\
&=\frac{12}{3}\\
&=4\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thank you, but it seems hard to solve, especially when you have power of 3 or 4.

Comment: When doing limits, I much prefer to have a variable approaching zero, so I manipulate things till that happens.

Comment: Can you give an example on one of the excercises i showed here please?

Answer (score 0):

Also, by the definition of a derivative we obtain: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow10}\frac{x-10}{\sqrt{3x+6}-6}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\cdot\frac{1}{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow10}\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{12}}{x-10}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{x+2}\right)'_{x=10}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\cdot2\sqrt{10+2}=4.$$

Comment: The limit of the derivate is always the same as the limit of the original function? And thank you.

Comment: @Alon It's not always so.